# ¿Se puede rastrear el origen de los sinónimos comestibles de "bofetada"?

Tags: historia, sinónimos, sustantivos

Según el diccionario:

> **[bofetada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5krATBH)**
>
> De or. inc.; cf. ingl. buffet 'puñetazo, manotazo'.
>
> 1. f. Golpe que se da en el carrillo con la mano abierta.

No sé si será por la proximidad del carrillo a la boca, pero el caso es que tanto esta palabra como otras similares como *puñetazo* y demás tienen una cierta variedad de sinónimos que "se comen", algunos suaves y otros más blasfemos. Negritas mías (con enlaces al DLE):

> *Ya la dije que soltara o la atizaba una chuchada y ella que dónde y cuándo nos veíamos y que mientras no la respondiera no había nada que hacer. Se me calentaron los cachos, me olvidé que era una, la solté **una [galleta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ilb6iyw)** y paré el trasto.*
>
> Miguel Delibes, "Diario de un emigrante", 1958 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Un miliciano definió así al francés: "Sabe decir allo como nadie y puede pegarte **una [torta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a7yncrp)** en cuatro idiomas."*
>
> José María Gironella, "Un millón de muertos", 1961 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *—¡A ver si te cierro la boca de **una [hostia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ki2xstc)**!*
>
> Elena Quiroga, "Escribo tu nombre", 1965 (España).

Y la última cortesía de Astérix ([enlace al DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7qVigfP)):

[image: Astérix y la castaña]

Se entienden estos sinónimos como originados por el hecho de que las bofetadas, al ir dirigidas a la cara, son algo que "te comes". Pero ¿cuál fue el primer "sinónimo comestible" de *bofetada*? ¿Se puede rastrear el origen de estos "sinónimos comestibles"? (No de cada uno en particular, sino de todos ellos en conjunto como fenómeno del lenguaje.) Veo por los ejemplos del CORDE que pueden parecer algo reciente, ¿son una invención del siglo XX o los hay anteriores?

Comment: también bebibles como *leche* y he descubierto ahora mismo *chuleta* que no sabía que también significaba bofetada.

Comment: @blonfu interesantes tus ejemplos, y en otro orden de cosas he visto que "bebible" no sería exactamente la contrapartida de "comestible". Ese honor lo tiene "[potable](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TqwWRTE)", y coloquialmente (te lo creas o no) "[bebestible](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5Gqznrv)". :-)

Comment: por cierto, lo que llevo viviendo en mi Colombia (casi toda mi vida) y lo que he podido ver por señal de televisión extranjera de canales peruanos, argentinos o mexicanos, canciones de grupos de estos lados del océano y leer de escritores hispanohablantes o de doblaje hispano, no recuerdo términos 'comestibles' para golpes. Cabe preguntarse si solo son términos peninsulares

Answer (score 3):

Encontré graciosa la pregunta (yo no sé cómo lo haces para encontrar preguntas interesantes por todos lados) y me puse a buscar algún otro ejemplo.

Los chilenos decimos *dar una **chuleta***, por "patear". Una chuleta es una costilla o una pieza de carne con costilla.

En Argentina, un ***bife*** es tanto un filete de vacuno como una bofetada.

Y no sé dónde se usan, pero el diccionario menciona ***catite*** (un "pilón pequeño hecho con azúcar muy refinado", es decir, un pan dulce) y ***chufa*** (un tubérculo dulce que se usa para hacer horchata), ambos también con el significado de tortazo.

No creo que en definitiva se pueda rastrear el origen de estas expresiones. Me imagino que probablemente existen en otros idiomas y que son derivados humorísticos de una idea similar a

> **[tapaboca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z6WqVJZ)**
>
> De *tapar* y *boca*.
>
> 1. m. Golpe que se da en la boca con la mano abierta.
> 2. m. coloq. Razón, dicho o acción con que se hace callar a alguien, especialmente cuando se le convence de que es falso lo que dice.

no en el sentido físico de que la boca está cerca de la mejilla, sino dando a entender que un golpe es, en definitiva, el argumento más poderoso de todos. Con una bofetada te dejo callado, como si estuviera metiéndote un pedazo de pastel en la boca.

Hay una palabra que me permitió buscar un poco más hacia atrás:

> **[mojicón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PXRUWE7)**
>
> De *mojar* e -*icón*.
>
> 1. m. Especie de bizcocho, hecho regularmente de mazapán y azúcar, cortado en trozos y bañado.
> 2. m. Especie de bollo fino que se toma principalmente con chocolate.
> 3. m. coloq. Golpe que se da en la cara con la mano.

La etimología la comparte Corominas, y agrega que es "una especie de bizcocho remojado".

Hay un texto de 1623, [Encomio de los Ingenios Sevillanos](https://archive.org/stream/AMont08219/AMont08219_djvu.txt), de Juan Antonio de Ibarra, donde se dice lo siguiente:

> AL muchachos del patria de Loiolas
>
> que mal pulgas le estas, diablo le entregas.
>
> con mal trato que das, hazes reniegas
>
> vaya i grita le das, hazes mamolas.
>
> Quando por rabias hazes, pisas colas,
>
> si al huyes quieres por escapas bregas,
>
> con **moxicon** que das, i coz que pegas
>
> rodando a infierno arrojas como bolas [...]

Si aceptamos la etimología del DRAE, aquí hay un ejemplo del siglo de oro en el que se dan patadas y bizcochos.

Answer (score 2):

Sin tener datos delante para demostrarlo parece que el origen vendría del hecho de que te van a dar un golpe o una bofetada en la boca, y se hace el símil de que es como si te la comieras.

Ahora bien, si te preguntas por qué esas comidas en concreto yo diría que tiene algo que ver con la forma de la mano al dar el golpe. Una bofetada con la mano abierta tiene forma de hostia, de galleta o de torta.

Sin haber visto otros ejemplos este parece un motivo lógico. Si me presentas el ejemplo de la castaña te diré que jamás he oído "dar una castaña" en España, aunque sí he oído "castañazo"; en este caso diría que como una castaña está tan dura y si te lanzan una debe de doler, si te dan un golpe te puede doler tanto como un castañazo, y de ahí la expresión. Yo lo comparo con otros ejemplos como que algo te siente "como un tiro", que también debe de doler bastante.

Comment: En realidad no me preguntaba el origen de cada expresión concreta, sino de todas ellas en general. Es decir, cuál fue la primera expresión documentada de un sinónimo comestible de "bofetada", y cuándo fue. Pero te agradezco tu respuesta igualmente y el tiempo que te has tomado para hacerlo.

Comment: Me temo que eso ya sí que ni idea. Me quedo observando por si alguien la responde, ya por curiosidad.