# ¿Cómo llegó "hostia" a significar "Golpe, trastazo, bofetada"?

Tags: etimología, vulgaridades

La tercera acepción de "[hostia](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=lF3mf78yrDXX2iowr0Sh)" es el vulgarismo malsonante

> Golpe, trastazo, bofetada.

Puedo entender algunas de estas expresiones como `ser la hostia/de la hostia`, por comparación con algo que, en el contexto religioso, representa algo extraordinario, sublime, etc.

He intentado encontrar la razón por la que esta palabra acabó evolucionado hacia un vulgarismo que significa "golpe", pero no he tenido éxito.

¿Sabe alguien cómo llegó "hostia" a significar "Golpe, trastazo, bofetada"?

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23196/1674) aventuraron una hipótesis con el símil de _recibir_ la hostia consagrada. No tiene referencias, eso sí

Answer (score 3):

La razón de esto está probablemente ligada también a la pregunta del por qué de la denominación de golpes varios  referenciando  *comidas*: 
**el de ser cosas que se reciben o propinan en la boca**.

Referir el dar una torta, un chuletazo, —o un bollo o un bife, en Argentina— es una forma irónica y socarrona, de aludir a algo de sentido bastante menos placentero.

Mi punto es que no casualmente otra denominación del puñetazo, es ***trompada***, ergo que aterriza en la ***[trompa](https://dle.rae.es/trompa?m=form)***, o sea en la boca o alrededores (en Argentina es común decir que alguien `*se comió* una piña`)

En el caso de la hostia, el sarcasmo se acentuaría por la  contradicción radical con su sentido principal, de *alimento bendito*. (Igualmente, le cabe el valor adjetivante de hostia como algo *grande y extraordinario*, es decir para hablar, no de uno cualquiera, sino de un "tremendo" golpe)